# How to successfully kill a java process and restart it in unix?

Tags: java, unix, process, centos, kill

I've been trying to run my java program overnight but I need to restart it sometimes to save it's progress and completely reboot the machine.  After a few hours I have the program save its progress and execute a little restart file to restart the program.

```
void restartServer() {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        rt.exec("./restart.bat");
    } catch (java.io.IOException err) {
        logError(err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Inside restart.bat I have:

```
echo Restarting Server
killall -9 java
sleep 2;
nohup java -Xmx200m -classpath bin server.Main;
```

However it doesn't work.  It says:

```
[root@linode java]# ./restart.bat
Restarting Server
: no process killed
: command not found 3:
nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
: command not found 4:
[root@linode java]#
```

Why does it say no process killed when there is a java process running? And why does it say command not found? It never restarts the program either.

Comment: Wouldn't this potentially kill itself before managing to launch the new java process?

Comment: @Bengt Good point. I think that might happen.

Comment: Oops.  I forgot to put a sleep before the killall.  That should solve it I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting `#!/bin/sh` or something like it as the first line of your `restart.bat`

BTW, `.bat` is a very poor choice of extension on linux system.

Comment: @Kyle. If you are on Linux, yes.

Comment: Alex that did the trick thank you:) Before it would work I had to run dos2unix on the script. But it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of starting the app from the server itself, you could do a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ 1 ]
do
    nohup java -Xmx200m -classpath bin server.Main;
done
```

This will restart the process once it quits. And after your savestate just exit and it will restart automatically.

Comment: So if I execute this script to run in the background, I could exit the JVM, and this would restart it?

Answer (score 1):

is it safe for your JVM to be killed like that mid process?  If not, you might consider a JMX bean to check the program status and do the shutdown from inside the JVM.

Comment: Well in the program before I execute the restartServer() void I also execute a saveProgress() void.  I never thought about shutting down from inside the JVM.  I suppose I could call a shutdown, and execute the program after but sleep for a good 10-15 seconds, that should be enough time for it to shutdown?